# need help in finding original url - wireshark

Tags: wireshark

I'm using wireshark to capture data.

Now when I'm hitting sites, I can only see **Source - IPv4,Dest - IPv4**.

Is there anyway I get to know the exact url it hit.
Like :

```
https://www.reddit.com/r/meme
https://github.com/microsoft/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you setup a MITM proxy to decrypt the traffic up stream from Wireshark - there is no way to inspect the contents of HTTPS traffic. If you go to a site that supports HTTP (not secure), then you would be able to see the URL and Host header.

`mitmproxy` is a well known tool that provides this, though there are many methods of performing this decryption

Comment: thanks, i actually found that, last night..

Comment: now figuring way out to use it in my application..